# Redirect to another page and refresh destination

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure it out how i can do below -

What i am trying to do is to redirect to http://www.example.com/xyz/index.php page and then refresh destination (http://www.example.com/xyz/index.php) can i do that on onclick

```
<input class="submit" type="button" style="font-weight: normal;" 
                            onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http://www.example.com/xyz/index.php'; return false;" value="Back to web">
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Mona

Comment: Did you try your snippet? It works? Or what happens?

Comment: Why all this trouble if you could just use an anchor tag?

Comment: Why do you want to load a page and the refresh it, what is the point? Am I missing something?

Comment: I agree with @MelanciaUK. Why make a button that links to a page using JavaScript rathwer than use an anchor tag?

Comment: after you redirect you want to refresh redirected page or page from where it is redirected ..

Comment: thank you for reply.. i can use a tag or javascript that is fine.. i have gew things on destination page which needs refresh to load.. or take effect.. that the reason i need to do refresh...thank you in advance..

Comment: But if you're just loading the page, unless you load it, apply any changes and then refresh it, it will be exactly the same page.

Comment: melanciaUK.. yes that is true.. let me see what i can do.. Vaibs_cool i want to refresh the redirected page..

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable feedback..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's everything you need:

```
<a class="submit" style="font-weight: normal;" href="http://www.example.com/xyz/index.php">Back to web</a>
```

Comment: No problems. Glad to help.